# PHP - Do I still need to check IF ISSET?.... or is IF ($_GET) good enough?

Tags: php, get, isset

I'm using quite a few (`$_GET`) statements and want to know if it's necessary to check             `if (isset($_GET))` first?

I've read quite a few posts that suggest it is important to check IF ISSET first (the way I was taught to code), but they're all from around 2009. Now our programmer has coded without checking IF ISSET, and says that checking if isset isn't necessary and will just add load to the script.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

An example of the code is:

```
if ($_GET["option"])  { 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mycurlurl.com/blah);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
....
```

or another example is

```
if($_GET['type']=='reports') header('location: http://myurl.com/reports');
```

I'm wondering if it should all use ISSET and look like

```
if (isset($_GET["type"]) && ($_GET["type"] == "reports")) { header('location: http://myurl.com/reports'); }
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. His code doesn't give errors when I test the website or look in logs, but I'm not sure if there could be fatal errors for our users that we can't see.

Comment: `$_GET` should always be set, although it might be empty. You should check `isset($_GET['paramname'])`, but you don't need to check `isset($_GET)`.

Comment: Even in the CLI, `$_GET` is initialized to an empty array.

Comment: Unless your entire code is inside the same page; yes, do use `isset()`. However, it also helps to determine if something has been chosen/set, while using an `else` as an escape route if it isn't. If you don't, and that error reporting is ON, it will throw an `Undefined index` error. - *"will just add load to the script"* - define "load". Unless you've got hundreds of (*unnecessary*) conditions, I doubt it's going to put any "strain" on the server.

Comment: Another reason to use `isset()` and `if( == )` is this: If someone punches in `page.php?type` or `page.php?type=` just to try and mess something up (*hacker or nosey bugger*) and without the required parameter `page.php?type=reports`, you stand at being in for some nasty surprises, depending on what's inside the actual script.

Comment: I think ignoring isset is a OLDER thing instead of using isset. That is one of bad/lazy coding habit which spread out in PHP programmers. I am thinking if php had bad reputation in application security checks, This is one of reasons.

Comment: (Addendum) I stand corrected, it's an `Undefined index` "warning" and not an "error", [*as originally written*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418513/php-do-i-still-need-to-check-if-isset-or-is-if-get-good-enough#comment39651864_25418513).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include an `isset()` for $_GET, you'd get a `Undefined Index` PHP error so it is a good idea to check for the existence of `$_GET` before using it anywhere, even in an if condition. I'd highly suggest you include it as a good programming practice.
So, your code part with an `isset` check is a good practice

```
if (isset($_GET["type"]) && ($_GET["type"] == "reports")) { 
    header('location: http://myurl.com/reports'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the explanation for $_GET in the php manual,it says “**An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters”**. The word “associative array” clearly tells us what this error is. **If we access any array variable which is not set, it will throw a warning saying that the index is undefined**. Is this argument valid in our case? Let us test it. Let us rewrite you  code by checking if that form variable is set and then try to access that variable:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']))
{
$var1 = $_GET['type'];
if($var1=="reports")
  header('location: http://myurl.com/reports');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen plenty of code that doesn't use isset() checks, but I tend to use it whenever I code because 1.) better safe than sorry, and 2.) if you have error reporting enabled on php, it will throw a warning that an index doesn't exist if you are trying to get $_GET['something'].

It's good practice to make sure that data is there before you try and call/get it. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, using a variable or array element that isn't set is not an error. You'll just get a null value by default.

If you have error reporting enabled, it will issue a warning about the use of an undefined variable or index, but the code will usually still work as expected. It's good practice to check for this first, if nothing else to reduce clutter in the PHP log. There may be some cases where you need the test to get correct program logic, but if you're testing whether the variables are set to some specific value, as in the examples in your question, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for isset() or empty() is to check to see if the variable exists and has a value.

If $_GET['type'] is not defined at all, it'll throw a PHP Notice.

isset() and empty() both suppress this.

As well, if ($_GET['type']) { } alone is a bad check unless you're expecting a boolean value.

If $_GET['type'] is empty string, false or 0 it will not process the if.

```
isset() will accept empty string, false and 0.
empty() will accept all of those.
```

So really you should look at !empty() as it will verify that the variable holds some sort of value.

```
!empty() will not accept empty string, false, 0 or null.
!isset() will only accept null.
```